# What proportion of the positive integers satisfy $I(n) < \frac{2n}{n + 1} \leq I(n^2) < 2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, arithmetic-functions

Let

$$I(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$

be the abundancy index of the positive integer $x$.  Note that $\sigma(x)$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example,

$$\sigma(12) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 12 = 28.$$

My question is this:  What proportion of the positive integers satisfy the inequality
$$I(n) < \frac{2n}{n + 1} \leq I(n^2) < 2?$$

Note that we necessarily have $n > 1$ from the left-hand inequality.

(A similar question is posted in MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488443).)

Comment: What is the "abundancy index"? In particular, what is $\sigma(x)$? And why did you post on MO within 7 minutes of posting on MSE instead of waiting for responses there?

Comment: It seems likely that the asymptotic density is 0 using standard arguments.  What have you tried?

Comment: @ViditNanda, my short answer to your last question is that I am not so sure if this question can be considered a "research-level" question as per MO standards.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, I've tried polynomial division on the middle inequality, thereby getting the final result

$$2n^2 - 2n + 1 \leq \sigma(n^2) < 2n^2.$$

This means that the [abundance](http://oeis.org/A033880) $a(n^2) = \sigma(n^2) - 2n^2$ satisfies $1 - 2n \leq a(n^2) < 0$, while the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) $d(n^2) = 2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)$ satisfies $0 < d(n^2) \leq 2n - 1$.

Comment: @ViditNanda, $\sigma(x)$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function, thanks for clarifying!  Editing my post to reflect that now.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris :  The reason it's usually considered rude to post to multiple sites is this:  Someone might see the question on one site, not realize it's already been answered on the other site, and do a lot of unnecessary work trying to solve it for you.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg : Thank you for pointing that out, I certainly did not mean to be rude.  I am just another *amateur* MO/MSE OP looking for an answer to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $I(n^2)$ has a continuous limiting distribution (look up the Erd\H{o}s--Wintner theorem). Since your lower limit $2n/(n+1)$ converges to your upper limit of $2$ as $n\to\infty$, the continuity of the distribution function shows that the limiting proportion of $n$ satisfying your inequality is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @so-called-friend-don, appreciate it!  =)

Comment: I forgot to ask (and my apologies in advance if this is too dumb a question), but does your result imply that the *asymptotic density* or *limiting proportion* of $n$ satisfying the inequality

$$I(n^2) < \frac{2n}{n + 1},$$

is $1$?